# Using cloudinary-build-url, how to add Transformer instances to the buildVideoUrl() function?

Tags: javascript, image, npm, video, cloudinary

https://cloudinary-build-url.netlify.app/usage/transformer

This is a great package, but it doesn't appear to have support for looping gifs out of the box. The link above shows a way to create custom url sections such as "e_loop".

What I can't figure out is how to inject those properties into the URL constructor provided by the package.

```
    previewUrl = buildVideoUrl(animation_url, {
            cloud: {
                cloudName: 'my-cloud'
            },
            transformations: {
                format: 'gif',
                loop: 'infinite' // Does not work
            }
        });
```

The transformer methods would seem to be the answer (see example below), but I can't figure out how to get the Transformer instance into my buildVideoUrl call. Something like:

```
const trans = Transformer.toString([
    'c_thumb',
    'w_500',
    'h_500',
    'g_auto',
    [ 'e_grayscale' ]
  ])

    previewUrl = buildVideoUrl(animation_url, {
            cloud: {
                cloudName: 'my-cloud'
            },
            transformations: {
                format: 'gif',
                trans // adding the Transformer instance
            }
        });
```

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

So to use effects you need to pass it as a key value pair. Try this

```
import { buildVideoUrl } from 'cloudinary-build-url'

const src = buildVideoUrl('cld_rubix', {
    cloud: {
        cloudName: 'demo'
    },
    transformations: {
        format: 'gif',
        effect: {
            name: "loop",
        }
    }
});

console.log(src)
```

More here on how to use the different transformations: https://cloudinary-build-url.netlify.app/transformations/basic#effect

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Can you post the error you get with the above call?

Comment: There's no error, but the output url doesn't include the e_loop directive.

EDIT: It appears it does add the e_loop, my mistake!

Comment: awesome, that's good to hear :)